# Not able to render non ANSI characters in PDF using DOMPDF

Tags: php, html, pdf, dompdf, pimcore

I am trying to create a PDF using DOMPDF in Pimcore which functionality works absolutly fine, but I am having issues while trying to include non ANSI characters in PDF, like Thai, Koread, Chinese characters. Either they are getting converted to question marks or it returns Squere boxes.

Here is the Code I am using.

```
    public function downloadPdfTemplate(Request $request): Response
    {

        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
        $checkStatus = GeneralHelper::getUserAndRoleFromSession();
        $peId = $request && $request->get('id') ? $request->get('id') : 0;
        $userLanguage = $request && $request->get('language') ? $request->get('language') : $checkStatus[LANGUAGE];
        DataObject\PackagingElement::setHideUnpublished(false);
        $peData = DataObject\PackagingElement::getById($peId);

        if ($peData) {
            $pdfData = PackagingElementService::generatePePdf($peData, $userLanguage, $peId, true);

            // Configure Dompdf according to your needs
            $pdfOptions = new Options();
            $pdfOptions->set('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);
            $pdfOptions->set('isPhpEnabled', true);
            $pdfOptions->set('isFontSubsettingEnabled', true);
            $pdfOptions->set('isRemoteEnabled', true);
            $fontPath = PIMCORE_PROJECT_ROOT.'/public/bundles/frontend/css/fonts/NotoSansThai.ttf'; // Update the path accordingly
            $pdfOptions->setFontDir(PIMCORE_PROJECT_ROOT . '/public/bundles/frontend/css/fonts/');
            $fileContents = file_get_contents($fontPath);
            $html = $this->renderView('@Frontend/packingElements/model/download-pdf-template.html.twig', $pdfData);
            $dompdf = new Dompdf($pdfOptions);
            $canvas = new CPDF([0, 0, 200, 200], "portrait", $dompdf);
            $fontMetrics = new FontMetrics($canvas,$pdfOptions);
            $fontMetrics->registerFont(['family'=>'Noto Sans Thai', 'style'=>'normal', 'weight'=>'normal'],
                $fontPath);
            $dompdf->setFontMetrics($fontMetrics);
            $dompdf->loadHtml($html,'UTF-8');
            $dompdf->render();
            $output = $dompdf->output();

            $pdfagicode = $pdfData['agiCode'];
            $globdesc = $pdfData['globalDescription'];
            $gd = GeneralHelper::replaceSpecialCharacters($globdesc);
            $pdfFilepath = $folderName . '/PE_' . $pdfagicode . '_' . $gd . '.pdf';
            file_put_contents($pdfFilepath, $output);

            // Output the generated PDF to Browser (force download)
            $dompdf->stream('PE_' . $pdfagicode . '_' . $gd . '.pdf', [
                'Attachment' => true,
            ]);
            unlink($pdfFilepath);
        } else {
            return $this->redirect('/packaging-element');
        }

    }
```

Here is my sample HTML I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;" charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+HK:wght@600&family=Noto+Sans+JP:wght@600&family=Noto+Sans+KR:wght@600&family=Noto+Sans+SC:wght@600&family=Noto+Sans+TC:wght@600&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet" crossorigin>

        <style>

            /** Define now the real margins of every page in the PDF **/
            body {
                margin-top: 4cm;
                margin-left: 0.5cm;
                margin-right: 0.5cm;
                margin-bottom: 1.8cm;
                border-top: 1px solid #a0a0a0 !important;
                font-family: 'Noto Sans HK', 'Noto Sans JP', 'Noto Sans KR', 'Noto Sans SC', 'Noto Sans TC', 'Noto Sans Thai','Noto Sans Tai Viet', DejaVu Sans, sans-serif

            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Thai text สวัสดี</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please let me know If anyone have any suggestions on this.

**Also If possible add solution for Korean, Chinese, Japanese, Vietnamese.**

Comment: I'm not saying this will help, but I noticed that your sample HTML is written in [XHTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML). This is an old standard. Why not write your HTML in [HTML5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) like most other web pages? It takes relatively little effort. See: [A Beginner's Guide to HTML5](https://blog.hubspot.com/blog/tabid/6307/bid/5847/a-marketer-s-guide-to-html5.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you use a font which supports your language (e.g. Noto Sans Thai font which supports Thai characters)

So say use the following (for thai):

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Black+Han+Sans&family=Noto+Sans+Thai:wght@100..900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<style>

.noto-sans-thai {
  font-family: "Noto Sans Thai", sans-serif;
  font-optical-sizing: auto;
  font-weight: <weight>;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variation-settings:
    "wdth" 100;
}


</style>
```

then use something like

```
 <p class="noto-sans-thai">
         สวัสดี Stackoverflow Ken Lee สวัสดี
    </p>
```

Fully working code:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;


$html = <<<HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Black+Han+Sans&family=Noto+Sans+Thai:wght@100..900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<style>

.noto-sans-thai {
  font-family: "Noto Sans Thai", sans-serif;
  font-optical-sizing: auto;
  font-weight: <weight>;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variation-settings:
    "wdth" 100;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="noto-sans-thai">
        สวัสดี Stackoverflow Ken Lee สวัสดี
    </p>
</body>
</html>
HTML
;

//$_dompdf_show_warnings = true;
//$_dompdf_debug = true;

$tmp = sys_get_temp_dir();

$dompdf = new Dompdf([
    'logOutputFile' => '',
    // authorize DomPdf to download fonts and other Internet assets
    'isRemoteEnabled' => true,
    // all directories must exist and not end with /
    'fontDir' => $tmp,
    'fontCache' => $tmp,
    'tempDir' => $tmp,
    'chroot' => $tmp,
]);

$dompdf->loadHtml($html);

$dompdf->render();

$dompdf->stream('hello.pdf', [
    'compress' => true,
    'Attachment' => false,
]);
```

See result below:

[image]

**-Additional Points-**

In case you want to display other languages, you need to use the correct font for that language, so see the following:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;


$html = <<<HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Black+Han+Sans&family=Noto+Sans+Thai:wght@100..900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+TC:wght@100..900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+SC:wght@100..900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+JP:wght@100..900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+KR:wght@100..900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<style>

.noto-sans-thai {
  font-family: "Noto Sans Thai", sans-serif;
  font-optical-sizing: auto;
  font-weight: <weight>;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variation-settings:
    "width" 100;
}

.noto-sans-TC {
  font-family: "Noto Sans TC", sans-serif;
  font-optical-sizing: auto;
  font-weight: <weight>;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variation-settings:
    "width" 100;
}

.noto-sans-SC {
  font-family: "Noto Sans SC", sans-serif;
  font-optical-sizing: auto;
  font-weight: <weight>;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variation-settings:
    "width" 100;
}

.noto-sans-JP {
  font-family: "Noto Sans JP", sans-serif;
  font-optical-sizing: auto;
  font-weight: <weight>;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variation-settings:
    "width" 100;
}

.noto-sans-KR {
  font-family: "Noto Sans KR", sans-serif;
  font-optical-sizing: auto;
  font-weight: <weight>;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variation-settings:
    "width" 100;
}



</style>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="noto-sans-thai">
        สวัสดี Stackoverflow สวัสดี
    </p>
    <p class="noto-sans-TC">
        圖書館 Stack Overflow  圖書館
    </p>
    <p class="noto-sans-SC">
        图书馆 Stack Overflow  图书馆
    </p>
    <p class="noto-sans-KR">
       라이브러리 스택 오버플로 라이브러리
    </p>
    <p class="noto-sans-JP">
        ライブラリ スタック オーバーフロー ライブラリ
    </p>
</body>
</html>
HTML
;

//$_dompdf_show_warnings = true;
//$_dompdf_debug = true;

$tmp = sys_get_temp_dir();

$dompdf = new Dompdf([
    'logOutputFile' => '',
    // authorize DomPdf to download fonts and other Internet assets
    'isRemoteEnabled' => true,
    // all directories must exist and not end with /
    'fontDir' => $tmp,
    'fontCache' => $tmp,
    'tempDir' => $tmp,
    'chroot' => $tmp,
]);

$dompdf->loadHtml($html);

$dompdf->render();

$dompdf->stream('hello.pdf', [
    'compress' => true,
    'Attachment' => false,
]);
```

See below for result (note: I do not know Vietnamese so cannot find the font, please search by yourself for Vientamese)

[image]

Comment: Tried but it is now working.

Comment: Please refer to my revised answer showing a 100% working example (for thai language). For other languages, please use the correct font

Comment: Hi , I tried the above solution it is working fine for Thai, So I tried other languages like Korean, Chinese, Japanese, Vietnamese , and I am having issues with them as well while rendering , can you please help in that.

Comment: For other languages, please use the correct `font for that language`

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide here, I tried 4-5 languages but none of them worked for me. Thank you for support.